# for and while loop confusion from brackeys 7th tutorial video

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
using System;

namespace SeventhConsoleProject
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random NumGen = new Random ();
            int diceRoll = 0;   // The variable used to roll the dice
            int attempts = 0;   // The amount of times it takes Tom to get a 6
            int amountmodifier = 10;    //To edit the amount of times that the program loops so that I can get a more accurate average

            Console.Write ("Tom wants to roll a dice multiple times and see how long it takes to get a 6.\nTom wants to get the average of " + amountmodifier + " successful attempts ");
            Console.ReadKey ();
            Console.WriteLine ();

            for (int amount = 1; amount <= amountmodifier; amount++) {
                while (diceRoll != 6) {
                    diceRoll = NumGen.Next (1, 7);
                    attempts++;
                }
            }
            int averageafter = attempts / amountmodifier;

            Console.WriteLine ("Over " + amountmodifier + " successful attempts it took Tom an average of " + averageafter + " attempts to get a 6");
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

I just recently watched Brackey's 7th video in his tutorial series on c#. I am trying to complete the challenge he left in the comments.

The initial task was to create a program in which "Tom" rolls a dice and he keeps rolling the dice until he gets a 6. The user is then suppose to be informed on how many times it took "Tom" to roll the dice before he got a 6. That part I figured out.

However, the challenge part is you have to figure out how to find the average of 10 successful attempts of "Tom" rolling a 6. This part is confusing me. My logic behind my code is that the for loop will repeat 10 times or whatever amount of times I change the variable `amountmodifier` to be. Every time the for loop goes through its loop it will go through a while loop which will continue until the "Tom" rolls a 6 once "Tom" rolls a 6 the while loops will exit and the for loop will run another time and that will repeat 10 times.

My idea is that the amount of "attempts" will have the information of 10 successful attempts after the for loop is complete and it will be divided by the `amountmodifier` to create the average of those attempts. However it will not work. From what I can conclude either the for loop is not repeating 10 times or the `attempts` amount is constantly resetting. I can't understand why. If anyone would explain I'd genuinely be so appreciative.

Comment: Thank you Soviut for editing my question to make it easier to read. That's really awesome of you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (int amount = 1; amount <= amountmodifier; amount++) {
    // Add this line:
    diceRoll = 0;

    while (diceRoll != 6) {
        diceRoll = NumGen.Next (1, 7);
        attempts++;
    }
}
```

The issue is that after a 6 is rolled, the value of `diceRoll` is 6. So the next time through the `for` loop, you never enter the `while` loop at all, since `diceRoll` is already 6.

The fix is to add the line I suggested to make sure `diceRoll` is reset to 0 (as you have it originally).

Even better, since you don't need to use `diceRoll` anywhere else, would be to just declare it right there:

```
for (int amount = 1; amount <= amountmodifier; amount++) {
    int diceRoll = 0; // and get rid of the similar line at the top of Main
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. This problem was confusing me for some long. I never realized the diceRoll was the problem. You really saved me from a huge headache! I can't put to words how thankful I am. You are awesome!